# Count element between 3 tables with mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got these 3 tables:

`___Kardex`

```
|--------|---------|-------------|
| KDX_Id | KDX_VIP | KDX_Regular |
|--------|---------|-------------|
| 1      |      No |          No |
| 2      |      No |          No |
|--------|---------|-------------|
```

`___BillableDatas`

```
|--------|---------------|
| BIL_Id | BIL_BookingId |
|--------|---------------|
| 1      |            99 |
| 2      |            99 | 
| 3      |           100 | 
|--------|---------------|
```

`___Bookings`

```
|--------|--------------|
| BOO_Id | BOO_ClientId |
|--------|--------------|
|     99 |            1 |
|    100 |            2 | 
|--------|--------------|
```

I want to loop into `___Kardex` and count for each client:

- The number of bookings the client booked (containing in ___Bookings).

- The number of nights the client spent (containing in ___BillableDatas).

So I tried:

```
SELECT 
    KDX_Id, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(BOO_Id) 
        FROM ___Bookings
        WHERE ___Kardex.KDX_Id = ___Bookings.BOO_ClientId
    ) AS nb_bookings,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(BIL_Id) 
        FROM ___BillableDatas
        WHERE ___Kardex.KDX_Id = ___Bookings.BOO_ClientId
        AND ___Bookings.BOO_Id = ___BillableDatas.BIL_BookingId
    ) AS nb_bookings 
FROM  ___Kardex
```

But I get empty datas.

Could you please help ?

Here the SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf1832

The expected result is:

```
|--------|-------------|-----------|
| KDX_Id | nb_bookings | nb_nights |
|--------|-------------|-----------|
| 1      |           1 |         2 |
| 2      |           1 |         1 |
|--------|-------------|-----------|
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does "empty datas" mean?  If you are getting no rows, then the `WHERE` is filtering out all the rows -- nothing is active.  And that would make sense, given that your sample data has not column called `KDX_status`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: sorry, the actual query returns this error: `Unknown column '___Bookings.BOO_ClientId' in 'where clause'`.

Comment: Your query has syntax error.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf1832/9: it actually works but just for `nb_bookings `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go :

```
SELECT 
    KDX_Id, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(BOO_Id) 
        FROM ___Bookings
        WHERE KDX_Id = ___Bookings.BOO_ClientId
    ) AS nb_bookings,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(BIL_Id) 
        FROM ___Bookings, ___BillableDatas
        WHERE ___Bookings.BOO_Id = ___BillableDatas.BIL_BookingId
        AND KDX_Id = ___Bookings.BOO_ClientId
    ) AS nb_nights 
FROM  ___Kardex
```

Comment: Ho, I missed this part `FROM ___Bookings, ___BillableDatas`. Thanks a lot Korteby Farouk.